# Login session lost after flex chart is displayed from jsp

Tags: java, apache-flex, jsp

I have a java web application. When I log in to that application and navigate to a jsp which has flex chart embeded into it, the chart displayes just fine. I am using blaze ds remoting object mechanism. But when I want to navigate to a different page, it logs me out of application since the login session is lost.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP session is backed by a HTTP cookie which is tied to a specific domain and by default also the context path. So if you lose the session, then it may be caused by navigating to a different domain and/or context path. It's however also possible to invalidate the session programmatically by calling [`HttpSession#invalidate()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29).

So to fix your problem, you need to ensure that you're navigating to a page in the same domain and context and that your server side code is not unnecessarily calling `invalidate()` somewhere.

If the problem is actually caused by a switch in the context path and you'd like to get it fixed, then you need to configure it in the servletcontainer. It's unclear which one you're using, but in for example [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) you would like to set the `emptySessionPath` attribute of the `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml` to `true`. Also see [this document](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html).